# ActionMailer not delivering mail in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am trying to build a password reset email. I am Using Rails 3.2.16, and Ruby 1.9.3p327, I have read a ton of answers to this question and tried pretty much everything. I have also gone through the [action mailer basics guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), and as far as i can see this should be working but its just not going well. Ill do a step by step guide of how i set it up.

firstly since i am trying to get this working in development, within `development.rb` **Note:** *I have reset the application each time i edited the development.rb file.*

```
#this is all the action mailer settings i have defined in development.rb
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true # Set to true so that errors would be visible.
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true # I read about this possible fix on SO
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: "boogle.dev"
}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.office365.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mpowered.co.za",
  :user_name            => "support@mpowered.co.za",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

My notifier class which inherits from ActionMailer

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Mpowered - BEEtoolkit <support@mpowered.co.za>"

  def deliver_password_reset_email(user)
    @edit_password_reset_url = edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)
    @name = user.name

    mail(
      subject:       "Password Reset Instructions",
      to:            user.email,
      date:          Time.now,
      content_type:  "text/html")
  end
end
```

Within my User model i have set up the method which will send the mail along with setting up of a perishable_token

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token!
  Notifier.deliver_password_reset_email(self)
end
```

The Passwords reset controller is set up like this:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user
  before_filter :load_user_using_perishable_token, :only => [ :edit, :update ]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user
      @user.deliver_password_reset_instructions!
      flash[:notice] = "Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you"
      render action: :new
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "No user was found with email address #{params[:email]}"
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user.password = params[:password]
    # Only if your are using password confirmation
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:password]

    # Use @user.save_without_session_maintenance instead if you
    # don't want the user to be signed in automatically.
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Your password was successfully updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render action: :edit
    end
  end


  private

  def load_user_using_perishable_token
    @user = User.find_using_perishable_token(params[:id])
    unless @user
      flash[:error] = "We're sorry, but we could not locate your account"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

I added resources to my routes:

```
resources :password_resets, :only => [ :new, :create, :edit, :update ]
```

My views are simple:
in app/views/password_resets/new.haml.html

```
%br
= form_tag password_resets_path, class: 'form-inline' do
  %legend Forgotten Password
  %p Enter your email address and instructions to reset your password will be emailed to you:
  %span.span1
    = label_tag :email, 'Email'
  = text_field_tag :email
  = submit_tag 'Reset my password', class: 'btn'
%br
```

So this should send the mail once you submit a valid email.
You should then receive an email with this content: app/views/notifier/password_reset_instructions.html.haml

```
%h1 Password Reset Instructions

%p
  A request to reset your password has been made. If you did not make
  this request, simply ignore this email. If you did make this
  request, please follow the link below.

= link_to "Reset Password!", @edit_password_reset_url
```

The link should bring you to a form where you can then save a new password and password confirmation.

app/views/password_resets/edit.html.haml

```
- if @user
  = form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path, :method => :put do |f|
    %legend Change My Password
    %p Please select a new password for your account
    .span8
      = f.field :password, :field_type => :password_field, :label => "New password"
      = f.field :password_confirmation, :field_type => :password_field
    .clearfix
    = f.submit "Update my password", class: 'btn'
- else
  %h3 We couldn't identify your reset code
  %p We're sorry, but we could not locate any accounts with reset codes that matched yours.
  %p If you are having difficulties resetting your password, try copying and pasting the URL from your password reset email into your browser or restarting the password reset process.
```

to which you can save your new password and then login once more.. this is what i have set up in the app. but everytime i try send it by following the system, it says the email was sent but nothing ever comes. I have also tried loading up a user in the console and then running `u.deliver_password_reset_instructions!`

and i get this:

[image]

But still no email in my inbox. I have currently set the email address in the notifier to my own personal one so no matter what valid email address is requested, the email should come to me.

I have been hitting walls for the last 12 hours and have no idea where to turn. i am hoping i have made a balls up that a fresh pair of eyes can catch.

Comment: `host: "boogle.dev"` ?

Comment: Thats for pow, i believe. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views for generating URLS in the mail.

Comment: @TheLegend If i haven't mistaken you have forgotten to write `.deliver` when calling your mailing function change this and try once `  Notifier.deliver_password_reset_email(self).deliver`

Comment: @anusha +1 - Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @TheLegend did you tried what `anusha` said?

Comment: yeah that was it hey! thanks. i feel kinda like i should take a vacation. haha thank you again

Comment: @TheLegend If my answer helpful to you please accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **.deliver** when calling Mailer method like this

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token!
  Notifier.deliver_password_reset_email(self).deliver
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I got a penny for each time I've missed that. :)